# Define a ruby function to wrap %x

Tags: ruby

I want to define a function to wrap `%x` as below

```
def myx(arg)
  puts %x("#{arg}")
end
```

It's OK to call `myx("ls")` but failed to call `myx("ls /usr")`. The error message is

> sh: 1: ls /usr: not found

I understand the error. It's because that the whole word `ls /usr` is taken as a single argument passed to the shell.  But how can I fix the problem?

Comment: why not `def myx(arg); puts \`#{arg}\`; end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not quote the command line with `"` in `%x`.

```
arg = "ls /usr"
%x("#{arg}")
```

will send the `"ls /usr"` as a single argument to the system, as if you execute the following in shell:

```
$ "ls /usr"
```

The system will try to locate a command/executable named `ls /usr`, which leads to the problem you met. So update your method to the following will work

```
def myx(arg)
  puts %x(#{arg})
end
myx('ls /usr')
```

The previous answer

```
def myx(arg)
  puts %x("#{arg}")
end

myx('"ls /usr"')
```

works as if you execute the following in the shell:

```
$ ""ls /usr""
# which results in
$ ls /usr
```

That's not quoting the command, rather, it uses extra `"` to clear the quote.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you quote your entire command inside the string:

```
def myx(arg)
  puts %x("#{arg}")
end

myx('"ls /usr"')
```

Alternatively backticks don't require the string to be quoted:

```
def myx(arg)
  puts `#{arg}`
end

myx("ls /usr")
```

Even nicer in my opinion:

```
def myx(arg)
  system(*arg)
end

myx(['ls', '/usr'])
```

Outputs:

```
bin
games
include
lib
lib32
lib64
libx32
local
sbin
share
src
```

The first two pass the entire command as a string to the shell for execution. The last one bypasses the shell and ruby executes it itself.

Comment: What does the `'"ls /usr"'` means? Why tow quotes, a single and a double?